# Thermochromic material for low temperature?

Tags: paint

Is there any kind of thermochromic material and/or paint that is capable of changing its color in the range from 4-8°C (39-46°F)? I'm trying to paint a glass bottle and want a visual aid for its temperature.

Comment: It's not strictly thermochromic but LCD thermometers can cover this range so maybe there's something you can modify/attach ([example](http://www.thermometersdirect.co.uk/lcd-thermometer-tempstrip-3degc-to--13degc.html))

Comment: Back in the 80s, you used to be able to get these thermometers that were a plastic card, and the ink would change on it depending on the temperature, and tell you what temperature they were.  It seems to be called a [liquid crystal thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal_thermometer).  I don't know if it's possible to get sensitivity at the temperatures you're looking for, but if they make ones for fridges, I would assume so.  This might also be the tech behind the winter gloves that would change when they got cold.

Comment: Currently [some beers](http://blitzlebels.com/super-cool-labels/) have labels with elements that appear or change color around that temperature range ("perfect for drinking")

Answer (score 1):

I found a supplier of raw thermochromic pigment active in the temperature range you are looking for. But to make it into paint you would have to add binder yourself.

Company is called [Shenzhen Yu Mingjie Pigments Co., Ltd.](http://ymjpigment.en.alibaba.com/product/60079015111-800321232/Color_Change_Thermochromic_Pigment_for_Cosmetics.html)

[image]

Has different thermochromic pigments active in the ranges -5C to 78C

Be sure to specify the temperature range you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

From this web site for [Hallcrest](http://www.thermographics.com/specialty-ink/thermochromic) is the following excerpt:

> Hallcrest thermochromic formulations are available as a pigment or a liquid crystal screen ink. Colors and temperatures can be customized to your application and printing capability. Thermochromic Temperature Range: -10ºC to 69ºC (14ºF to 156ºF)

They have standard activation temperatures of 15°C, 31°C and 47°C, and offer special activation temperatures in the range of -10°C to 69°C.

For email and telephone go to this [site](http://www.thermographics.com/about/contact-us).